Async pipe not updating view although subscribing and using the latest value of the attribute works in Angular
Consider the below snapshot that does't work:
Parent.ts 
allowed$ : Observable<boolean>;

Parent.html 
<child [allowed]="allowed$ | async">

Child.ts
@Input() allowed : boolean

Child.html
<div>{{allowed}}</div>

The below snapshot seems to work:
Parent.ts 
allowed$ : Observable<boolean>;

Parent.html 
<child [allowed$]="allowed$ | async">

Child.ts
@Input() allowed$ : Observable<boolean>;
allowed: boolean;

ngOnInit(){
this.allowed$.subscribe(latest => {this.allowed = latest})

Child.html
<div>{{allowed}}</div>

The change detection policy used is OnPush. Why does async pipe doesn't seem to update the variable while subscribing to it seems to be working?
Basically, the aysnc pipe was not working and doesn't seem to update the view so I tried using the subscribe method and it actually worked.

The problem doesn't come from the async pipe, it comes from the fact that Angular doesn't automatically detect input changes.
You have to either use the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook or you can use a setter instead of a regular input.
You can find a detailed answers on how to detect the change of an input in this StackOverflow question

When trying out the Stackblitz, the child works fine, since when the input changes the ngOnChanges triggers as expected, so I suspect it's due to the parent. I just called the detectChanges of ChangeDetectorRef whenever the @Input property of the parent got changed and it started working.
So change detection need to be manually fired for the child to know about the change from the parent. It works the same way, without the async pipe, update the parent, then fire change detection manually to propagate it.
MAIN
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent, AsyncPipe],
  template: `
    <app-child [allowed]="allowed$ | async"/>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class App {
  allowed$!: Observable<boolean>;
  allowed = false;
  cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);
  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.allowed$ = of(!this.allowed);
      this.allowed = !this.allowed;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }, 2000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

CHILD
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<div>{{allowed}}</div>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() allowed!: boolean | null;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(1);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
